# Avoiding power drain

Tags: battery-life, screen

I just got a samsung Indulge this weekend and I’ve noticed that the biggest power drain on the battery is from the display. I’m blind, so I really don’t need to be able to see it at all. Is there a way for me to turn it off completely like I do on other devices?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to turn the screen off completely but setting the screen brightness to the lowest possible value will help with battery life.

> Settings->Display->Brightness

Comment: Also, make sure to disable auto brightness (if available).

Comment: Thank you, though  I did that on the first day. I've also found a couple of battery saving apps that help dim it slightly more then standard. are there any apps out there that would be able to blank it completely? On my Apple devices this feature is built in to the OS as part of Voice Over. On my previous Samsung smart phone it was a feature of the screen reader that I used.

Answer (score 2):

There is this app.. [Screen Filter.](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor&feature=related_apps)  This would help you in achieving your desired brightness or rather making it completely off!

Comment: Screen filter might just be the right trick as it can reduce the display brightness and overlay a dark screen which you can adjust to a very low value to make the screen appear completely black. However, the backlight might still be there but a black screen consumes very little energy especially on certain types of screens (AMOLED I think)